# Using MariaDB in C

Tags: c, mariadb

I'm trying to connect to a MariaDB database in a C script and I can't find the necessary documentation. I installed libmariadbclient-dev, but I couldn't find any accompanying documentation such as a man page. There's a basic description and limited documentation [here](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/mariadb-client-library-for-c/), but the documentation only includes descriptions of functions. The fact is, despite having scoured all sorts of Google results, I don't even know what to import to get this to work, much less how to use it. Is there any guide or documentation on how to use a MariaDB database in C?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> The MariaDB Client Library for C has exactly the same API as the MySQL
>   Connector/C for MySQL 5.5

Here it is: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c-api-function-overview.html

Another one:
http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlc/

You can compile a minimal test like

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{  
  MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);

  if (con == NULL) 
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
      exit(1);
  }

  if (mysql_real_connect(con, "localhost", "root", "root_pswd", 
          NULL, 0, NULL, 0) == NULL) 
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
      mysql_close(con);
      exit(1);
  }  

  if (mysql_query(con, "CREATE DATABASE testdb")) 
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
      mysql_close(con);
      exit(1);
  }

  mysql_close(con);
  exit(0);
}
```

using

```
gcc -o mysql-test mysql-test.c $(mysql_config --libs)
```

Comment: thats helpfull, i didnt know it was the same, tks

Comment: @mf_ Because MariaDB is forked from MySQL, its like a open source version of MySQL

Comment: @DonNisnoni MySQL is also open source (although also available as non-open source).  I highly recommend reading on the story of those two databases and how the fork happened.