# Undefined references when linking mariadb C connector

Tags: c, mariadb

I've had some (too many) hours trying to make mariadb C connector to work with my own code. MySQL C connector worked fine, but I decided to migrate to mariadb.

Finally I decided to try a minimal code to check if the problem was with my code or the environment, and I got the same error. The code is from this question at SO: [Using MariaDB in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265471/using-mariadb-in-c).

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{  
  MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);

  if (con == NULL) 
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
      exit(1);
  }

  if (mysql_real_connect(con, "localhost", "root", "root_pswd", 
          NULL, 0, NULL, 0) == NULL) 
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
      mysql_close(con);
      exit(1);
  }  

  if (mysql_query(con, "CREATE DATABASE testdb")) 
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
      mysql_close(con);
      exit(1);
  }

  mysql_close(con);
  exit(0);
}
```

and tried to compile it with

```
gcc -v -o mysql-test mysql-test.c $(mariadb_config --libs)
```

expanded to

```
gcc -v -o mysql-test mysql-test.c $(mariadb_config --libs)
```

The output I got is

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-suse-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --infodir=/usr/share/info --mandir=/usr/share/man --libdir=/usr/lib64 --libexecdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,fortran,obj-c++,java,ada --enable-checking=release --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.3 --enable-ssp --disable-libssp --with-bugurl=http://bugs.opensuse.org/ --with-pkgversion='SUSE Linux' --disable-libgcj --disable-libmudflap --with-slibdir=/lib64 --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-libstdcxx-allocator=new --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --program-suffix=-4.3 --enable-linux-futex --without-system-libunwind --with-cpu=generic --build=x86_64-suse-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973] (SUSE Linux)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'mysql-test' '-L/usr/local/lib/mariadb' '-mtune=generic'
 /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/cc1 -quiet -v mysql-test.c -quiet -dumpbase mysql-test.c -mtune=generic -auxbase mysql-test -version -o /tmp/ccISncmQ.s
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/include
 /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/include-fixed
 /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C (SUSE Linux) version 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973] (x86_64-suse-linux)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973], GMP version 4.2.3, MPFR version 2.3.2.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 91a878d77972b76d647d592fefc786fc
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'mysql-test' '-L/usr/local/lib/mariadb' '-mtune=generic'
 /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/as -V -Qy -o /tmp/ccD2nseu.o /tmp/ccISncmQ.s
GNU assembler version 2.20.0 (x86_64-suse-linux) using BFD version (GNU Binutils; SUSE Linux Enterprise 11) 2.20.0.20100122-0.7.9
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/:/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/:/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/:/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/:/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/:/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/:/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../lib64/:/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/lib/:/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'mysql-test' '-L/usr/local/lib/mariadb' '-mtune=generic'
 /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/collect2 --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o mysql-test /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../lib64/crt1.o /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/crtbegin.o -L/usr/local/lib/mariadb -L/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3 -L/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/lib -L/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../.. /tmp/ccD2nseu.o -lmariadb -lssl -lnsl -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/crtend.o /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
/usr/local/lib/mariadb/libmariadb.so: undefined reference to `SSL_get_error@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/local/lib/mariadb/libmariadb.so: undefined reference to `SSL_get_peer_certificate@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/local/lib/mariadb/libmariadb.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/local/lib/mariadb/libmariadb.so: undefined reference to `SSL_set_ex_data@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/local/lib/mariadb/libmariadb.so: undefined reference to `X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/local/lib/mariadb/libmariadb.so: undefined reference to `SSL_get_ex_data@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/local/lib/mariadb/libmariadb.so: undefined reference to `SSL_write@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/local/lib/mariadb/libmariadb.so: undefined reference to `SSL_clear@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/local/lib/mariadb/libmariadb.so: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_THREADID_set_numeric@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/local/lib/mariadb/libmariadb.so: undefined reference to `SSL_COMP_get_compression_methods@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
...
```

LibOpenSSL 1.0.0 is installed and library in library path. I had to install libopenssl-devel, too.

At $LD_LIBRARY_PATH there is a libssl.so link to /lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0. If I execute

```
nm -g /usr/lib64/libssl.so
```

I get

```
nm: /usr/lib64/libssl.so: no symbols
```

libopenssl 0.9.8 is also installed

```
# rpm -qa | grep libopenssl
libopenssl0_9_8-0.9.8h-30.27.11
libopenssl-devel-1.0.0c-17.1
libopenssl0_9_8-32bit-0.9.8h-30.27.11
libopenssl1_0_0-1.0.0c-17.1
```

Any clue? Thanks!

**Updated:** Output of ldd

```
# ldd /usr/local/lib/mariadb/libmariadb.so
/usr/local/lib/mariadb/libmariadb.so: /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/local/lib/mariadb/libmariadb.so)
/usr/local/lib/mariadb/libmariadb.so: /lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/local/lib/mariadb/libmariadb.so)
/usr/local/lib/mariadb/libmariadb.so: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/mariadb/libmariadb.so)
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff2d90f000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f08bc078000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f08bbe73000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f08bbc1d000)
        libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f08bb9c1000)
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f08bb60f000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f08bb2b1000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f08bc521000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f08bb099000)
```

glicbc_2.14 not found, but it seems that libc.so.6 should be fine. At OpenSuse 11.4 repository glibc version is glibc-2.11.3-12.15.1.x86_64.rpm

**Update 2:** I succeeded in showing the symbos with

```
objdump -tT /usr/lib64/libssl.so
```

and the symbols are there

**Update 3 and solution (workaround):**

main problem is that libmariadb.so requires glibc 2.14, while at opensuse 11.4 glibc version is 2.11. Installing glibc 2.14 from opensuse 12.1 involved a severe upgrade of the system I could not do.

I also tried to use the connector from 2.0 series. It also failed with similar messages.

Next, I looked for 1.0 series. I read that previously the connector was named `libmariadbclient` and remembered that I installed a libmariadbclient package, so I changed linker flags to -lmariadbclient and... **it worked!**

But the linker didn't use the library from the libmariadbclient package, but the static library included with the connector (libmariadbclient.a). So linking statically the connector worked for me.

Comment: It is not clear which version of libopenssl is installed where and which symbolic link points to which version. Try adding `-L/path/to/dir/with/actual/openssl-1.0.0` (probably `-L/lib64`) before all other gcc arguments.

Comment: @n.m. The symbolic link points to openssl-1.0.0 library. I try the suggested solution, but I got the same error messages.

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB Connector/C requires OpenSSL 1.0.1 or newer.

See [Prerequisites For Building Connector/C From Source](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/prerequisites-for-building-connectorc-from-source/)

Please also note, that OpenSSL versions < 1.0.2 are eoled and might be vulnerable.

Comment: Thanks. IMHO main problem was that OpenSuse 11.4 repository was not consistent, as software in that repository doesn't see its requirements fulfilled by the versions of required packages shipped in it.