# How to compile with gcc on Mac OS using mariadb-connector-c

Tags: macos, gcc, mariadb, mariadb-connector-c

I have successfully installed mariadb and mariadb-connector-c on Mac OS Monterey using Homebrew but cannot figure out how to compile a simple c source file with `gcc`. If I try:

```
gcc -o test main.c
# main.c:1:10: fatal error: 'mysql.h' file not found
```

Trying something different, if I adapt the MySQL instructions for using its own connector-c [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/c-api-building-clients.html), I've tried:

```
gcc -o main main.c /usr/local/bin/mariadb_config
# ld: can't link with a main executable file '/usr/local/bin/mariadb_config' for architecture x86_64
```

Another thing I've tried is adapting the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17265849/19847712) for mariadb:

```
gcc -o test main.c $(mariadb_config --libs)
# main.c:1:10: fatal error: 'mysql.h' file not found
```

How can I compile a c program that uses mariadb-connector-c on Mac?

FYI, here is `main.c`:

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);

  if (con == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
    exit(1);
  }

  if (mysql_real_connect(con, "localhost", "(...)", "(...)", NULL, 0, NULL, 0) == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
    mysql_close(con);
    exit(1);
  }

  if (mysql_query(con, "CREATE DATABASE testdb"))
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
    mysql_close(con);
    exit(1);
  }

  mysql_close(con);

  printf("MySQL client version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());

  exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc needs to know where to find both MariaDB Connector/C include files (in most cases mysql.h) and the location and names of the MariaDB C/C libraries.

You can either specify them with `-I/include_path` `-L/library_path` `-lmariadb` or you can use mariadb_config:

```
gcc -o test main.c $(mariadb_config --include --libs)
```

Source: https://mariadb.com/docs/skysql-previous-release/connect/programming-languages/c/development/